# Fitting a set of points to a distribution by adding up to three degrees of freedom with Python

Tags: chi-squared

I have a set of points whose shape is as below
[image]

Its set of $x$ and $y$ points is as follows:

$x=[0.14741,0.180288,0.195,0.245342,0.25614,0.289377,0.315789,0.357143,0.431034,1.785714,2,2.323529,2.586207,3,3.894737,4.923077]$

$y=[0.211718,0.408906,0.507768,0.832,0.903626,1.092787,1.368377,1.750082,2.593839,1.72126,1.653633,1.567115,1.502963,1.419437,1.279676,1.153634]$

Can anyone fit a distribution with at least three degrees of freedom to these points? Do I need the name of the distribution and its coefficients? Does anyone have an idea of writing code with Python to get the coefficients and type of distribution? This chart is the most similar to the chi-square and Double Exponential charts.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: thank you, But my question is really this... .